# Does nodejs have multithreading under the hood?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I am trying Non-Blocking Code Example from this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm):

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('input.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(data.toString());
});

console.log("Program Ended");
```

Assume I have single processor CPU. Who manages CPU time between `callback function` and `console.log()` method? Does Nodejs core have something like Thread manager under the hood? How does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although LibUV (the library which does the IO in node.js) definitely use a small thread pool behind the scenes, the non-blocking IO itself does not use threads to be non blocking.

In a nutshell, you tell the operating system to initialize a non blocking IO action. the OS communicates with the relevant driver and then returns the flow back to the application. the relevant driver operates on its own without using threading model. when the IO finishes, the driver interrupts the OS which in it's turn notifies your application that the IO has being finished. your application then dequeues the associated callback and launches it.

the entire mechanism does not require extra threads. you use threads to parallelize CPU-based tasks and asynchronous IO to parallelize IO-based tasks.
the one which does the IO is not the CPU but a specialized hardware+driver, and therefor no need for extra threads.

Comment: Be careful, not all (non-blocking) I/O in node is done without threads. File I/O in particular is always done in the thread pool on most platforms. Also `dns.lookup()` (what node uses internally to resolve addresses) is currently done in the thread pool. General network I/O (e.g. the `net` module) on the other hand, *is* done without threads, everywhere.